# Extract multiple captured groups from sed to variables

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have the following text

```
abc <THIS> abc <THAT> abc <WHAT> abc
```

where `abc` is a placeholder for a well defined expression. I'd like to extract the 3 terms in the brackets and save them in 3 separate variables. Is is possible to do that without parsing the text 3 times? Basically I'd like to capture and somehow "export" multiple groups.

It's clear that I can extract one of them like this:

```
VARIABLE=`echo $TEXT | sed "s_abc <\(.*\)> abc <.*> abc <.*> abc_\1_g"`
```

But is it possible to get all 3 of them without running `sed` 3 times?

Other (portable) solutions without `sed` are also welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If there are any characters that you know will *not* appear in `THIS`, `THAT`, or `WHAT`, then you can write something like this:

```
IFS=$'\t' read -r VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 \
    < <(sed 's/^abc <\(.*\)> abc <\(.*\)> abc <\(.*\)> abc$/\1\t\2\t\3/' \
             <<< "$TEXT"
       )
```

telling `sed` to use that separator in its output, and `read` to use that separator in its input.

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
line='abc <THIS> abc <THAT> abc <WHAT> abc'
var=($(sed 's/[^<]*<\([^>]*\)>[^<]*/"\1" /g' <<<"$line"))
echo "first ${var[0]} second ${var[1]} third ${var[2]}"
first "THIS" second "THAT" third "WHAT"
```

Comment: What's the name of the `$(foo)` operator? Is that similar to `\`foo\``?

Comment: For anyone wondering now (10 years later), `$(foo)` is basically a safer version of `\`foo\`` that allows for nesting; this doesn't work: `\`foo \`bar\`\``, but this does: `$(foo $(bar))`

Answer (score 2):

No need to spawn a process:

```
var='abc <THIS> abc <THAT> abc <WHAT> abc'
var1=${var#abc <}          # Remove the leading 'abc <'.
THIS="${var1%%> abc <*}"   # Remove the longest trailing '> abc <*'.
var2="${var1#*> abc <}"    # Remove the shortest leading '*> abc <'.
THAT="${var2%%> abc <*}"   # Remove the longest trailing '> abc <*'.
var3="${var2#*> abc <}"    # Remove the shortest leading '*> abc <'.
WHAT="${var3%> abc}"       # Remove the trailing '> abc'
echo "$THIS"
echo "$THAT"
echo "$WHAT"
```